# Adding space between two Tables

Tags: jquery, html, excel

I have two different table data. I want to show both table data in one Excel worksheet.
In Excel, the first table data will get displayed, then below that the second table data will get displayed. I need a space after first table data.

I use `<br>` tag but it cannot give the space between two data. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I tried this:

```
function getZeroErlangBBHCellGridHtml(dataCollection, filter) {
    debugger;
    var htmlResult = '';
    var tableColumnHeaders, tableDataColumns = '';
    var htmlTable = '';
    tableColumnHeaders = "<tr><th>DATE</th><th>CIRCLE</th><th>TOTALCEELCOUNT</th><th>ZEROERLANGSCELLCOUNT</th><br></tr>";
    tableDataColumns = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><br></tr>";
    htmlTable = htmlTable + "<div><table  border=\"1\">";
    htmlTable = htmlTable + tableColumnHeaders
    $.each(dataCollection[0], function (index, nqi2G) {
        debugger;
        htmlTable = htmlTable + tableDataColumns.Stringformat(nqi2G.Date, nqi2G.Circle, nqi2G.TotalCeelCount, nqi2G.ZeroErlangsCellCount);
    });

    var tableColumnHeaders2, tableDataColumns2 = '';
    var htmlTable2 = '';
    tableColumnHeaders2 = "<tr><th><br>DATE</th><th>CIRCLE</th><th>CELLID</th></tr>";
    tableDataColumns2 = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>";
    htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + "<br><div><table  border=\"1\">";
    htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + tableColumnHeaders2
    $.each(dataCollection[1], function (index, nqi2G) {
        debugger;
        htmlTable2 = htmlTable2 + tableDataColumns2.Stringformat(nqi2G.Date, nqi2G.Circle, nqi2G.CellId);
    });

    htmlResult = htmlTable + htmlTable2 + "</table></div>";
    return htmlResult;
}
```

Thanks in advance
Harshal

Comment: What about putting `document.write("<br />");`

Comment: where should i put this ??  document.write("<br />");

Comment: Where you want the space to appear.(between the tables)

Answer (score 0):

`<br/>` is a line break...

You can add a margin style on the second div linke `<div style="margin-top:15px">` or you can replace the `<br>` tag with a new alinea  like this `<p>&nbsp;<p>`  (`&nbsp;` is a no breaking space to make sure the alinea is rendered)

Comment: Hi Thor .According to tour suggestion I used <p>&nbsp;<p> ,it gives me space before first table data .I want after first table data.Please guide me .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its hard without actually testing it, but I think the problem is with Table 1 not being terminated. Try changing the last code line with this one 'htmlResult = htmlTable + "</table></div>" + htmlTable2 + "</table></div>";'

Comment: No.its not working .'htmlResult = htmlTable + "</table></div>" + htmlTable2 + "</table></div>";' .its give only the first table data .it does not show second table data.

Comment: Can you post the output of the rendered table? That way it is a bit easier to look for the error.